Nordic curl - force at the ankle
So, there is an exercise called nordic curl. Looks something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_e9vFU9-tkc
It is sometimes performed with someone holding your ankles down. How does the physics of this work?
I mean... let's consider a 180cm and 90kg individual performing this exercise. Let's assume that everything below the knees weights 10kg only. So, this allows us to simplify the problem and divide the individual into a first-class lever with two arms and the knees acting as the fulcrum.
So, one arm (everything below the knees) is 40cm long and let's assume 10kg heavy and because the mass of the calf is let's assume distributed evenly, this produces 0.4x5=2kg=20NM. Fine.
But the other arm (everything above the knees) is 140cm long and 80kg heavy. Again, let's assume that this part has also weight distributed evenly. This outputs 1.4*40=56kg=560NM in the knees. (yeah, 1kg = 9.81N... let's simplify this away).
And now the fun part: 560NM at 40cm (distance between the knee and the ankle) yields 1400N. 1400N is at least 140kg. So the question is: how can someone weighting 50kg hold your ankles while you do the exercise and not be outweighted?
This is not a school question. I can usually understand why things happen, but this... I don't get this.


You're assuming the mass is all concentrated at the head instead of a uniform lever (a similar issue with your torque analysis at the ankle too).

@Triatticus, no, I'm not. All the mass in the head would output 1.4m*80kg=1120NM. Please note that I have divided the mass in half in my calculations to assume that it is evenly distributed across the body.

I think it's more about your setup now that I think about it...someone nearly 2 meters tall will likely have longer knee to ankle distance than you've given here, if you assume a split of 0.6m then you arrive at a helper mass of 75kg which is on par with a slightly smaller person helping you out.
